# CCCrypt fails when decrypting in another application

Tags: objective-c, encryption, cryptography

I have some Encryption and Decryption class methods in my application. I can encrypt 'data' using 'key' and it works great. I can write that data to disk and then read the data in at a later time using the application and call decryptWithKey to decrypt the data block. Everything works great. However, if I include this .m class file into another application, compile that application and try to decrypt that same data which was encrypted with the first application, the CCCrypt(decrypt) call fails...well, not exactly, it returns Success but the data is not decrypted. I have compared the data and key values in both applications and they are identical, down to the byte.

Any ideas?

```
+(BOOL)encryptWithKey:(NSMutableData*)data withKey:(NSString *)key
{
    CCCryptorStatus result = kCCSuccess;

   @try
    {
        char keyPtr1[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
        bzero( keyPtr1, sizeof(keyPtr1) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)
        [key getCString: keyPtr1 maxLength: sizeof(keyPtr1) encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
        size_t dataInLength = [data length];
        size_t dataOutLength = 18*dataInLength;

        [data setLength:dataOutLength];
        result = CCCrypt( kCCEncrypt,kCCAlgorithmAES128,kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                         (const void*)keyPtr1, kCCKeySizeAES256, 0 /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                         [data mutableBytes], dataInLength, /* input */
                                         [data mutableBytes], dataOutLength, /* output */
                                         &numBytesEncrypted );
        [data setLength:numBytesEncrypted]; 
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        WDCATCH(exception);

    }
    return ( result == kCCSuccess );
}

+(BOOL)decryptWithKey:(NSMutableData*)data plaintext:(NSString**)plaintext withKey:(NSString *)key
{
    CCCryptorStatus result = kCCSuccess;

    @try
    {
        // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
        char  keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
        char szPlaintext[1024]={0};
        bzero( keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)
        [key getCString: keyPtr maxLength: sizeof(keyPtr) encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;

        result = CCCrypt( kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                         (const void*)keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                         0 /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                         [data mutableBytes], [data length], /* input */
                         szPlaintext,1024,// [data mutableBytes], dataOutLength, /* output */
                         &numBytesEncrypted );
        if (result == kCCSuccess)
        {
            szPlaintext[numBytesEncrypted] = 0;
            *plaintext = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s",szPlaintext];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        WDCATCH(exception);

    }   return ( result == kCCSuccess );
}
```

Comment: Note that the above code is extremely insecure (see http://robnapier.net/blog/aes-commoncrypto-564 for details). The `18*dataInLength` is also very strange. At most, this needs to be `dataInLength+16`, but that should still work out (it's just too big). It is strange that you encrypt raw data, but then expect to decrypt ASCII (not even UTF-8) string. When you say the decryption fails, is `numBytesEncrypted` greater than 0? Perhaps the %s ASCII conversion is failing (though then you should get garbage). When you say "not decrypting," what is the actual symptom?

Comment: after CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt) executes, numBytesEncrypted (which should be renamed to numBytesDecrypted), is 0, szPlainText is empty and result is = 0/kCCSuccess.

Comment: I did some more poking around and it looks like it may have something to do with application 'A', the Encrypting application, being targeted to OSX 10.7 deployment/baseSDK and application 'B, the Decrypting application, being targeted to OSX 10.9 deployment/baseSDK; @RobNapier, could that cause problems?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Objective-C expert, but `char szPlaintext[1024]={0};` in the `decryptWithKey` seems very suspicious to me. First you allocate 1024 bytes, but then you assign the pointer to an array containing the element `0`? The generation of `plaintext` as a string looks pretty suspicious as well, but it probably works for ASCII encoded plaintext (?).

Comment: the ={0}; in the declaration will initialize the entire buffer to null/0, similar to a bzero or memset